# Проверка сайта на существование

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь проверить существование домена таким кодом:

```php
<?php
$domain = "http://www.example.com/";
$ch = curl_init($domain);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// загрузка страницы и выдача её браузеру
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($answer){
    echo "true";
} else { 
    echo "false";
}
```

Но не смотря на то, что домен зарегистрирован, оно не возвращает `true`. В чем может быть ошибка? В `CUrl` не особо силен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените эту строку:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

На эту:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Comment: Он ведь и так, удаляет специально тело документа, разве не так?

Comment: Ну если удаляет, то зачем его использовать? Просто ради того, чтобы была ещё одна строка кода? Если да, то можно все curl-директивы попрописывать с выключенным значением, но зачем?

Comment: Ну так он же удаляет этой строчкой тело документа. Если удалить эту строчку, мы получим и тело, и заголовки, а так в итоге только заголовки.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов точно ... Туплю ) Спасибо, сейчас подправлю ответ.

Comment: Ой, кому как не мне вас понимать...) Удачи.